# C delete one line from file not working

Tags: c

I have problem with my C program. I want to remove from the file selected line.
Working on two files, delete works fine, but after the removal of the program does not change the file name and does not remove the "old" file.

File structure

```
"new","new","new","1001" 
"asd","as","das","asd" 
"sdasda","asasd","dsaa","sdsda"
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DB "db.txt" 

int main()
{
                    FILE *f1;
                    FILE *f2;
                    char ch;
                    int linia, tmp = 1;
                    f1 = fopen(DB, "r"); 
                    printf(" \n Enter line number:"); 
                    scanf("%d", &linia);
                    f2 = fopen("kopia.txt", "a+");
                    ch = getc(f1);
                    while (ch != EOF)
                    {
                        ch = getc(f1);
                        if (ch == '\n')
                            {       tmp++;      }      
                        if (tmp != linia)
                            {putc(ch, f2);}
                    }
                    fclose(f1);
                    fclose(f2);
                    remove(DB); //not working
                    rename("kopia.txt",DB); //not working
                    printf("\n Done:\n");

                    return 0;
}
```

Comment: check the return status of remove and rename and, if != 0 print the error with strerror.

Comment: `#define DB db.txt` should probably be `#define DB "db.txt"`...?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, my bad in write post. Gets an error Permission denied

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I thought that but, if so, how did it compile?

Comment: where is `main`? format your code first.

Comment: `char ch;` Make that `int ch;` Aslo: your loop is wrong ( it writes 0xff  to the output when it encounters the EOF before breaking out of the loop (if it breaks out of the loop))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  ...
  int ch;
  while (1)
  {
    ch = getc(f1);
    if (ch == EOF) break;
    if (ch == '\n') tmp++;     
    if (tmp != linia) putc(ch, f2);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: I have a problem. How do I delete the data is removed '"' from the beginning of the line.

Comment: Sorry, I don't inderstand. What do you want to delete? A character, a word? a line? [maybe should ask another question]

Answer (score 1):

DB should be a macro for string type, but what I see in the code is db.txt wihout ", just replace it with "db.txt" and try..

This code should not be compiled because of this error, does it ?

another thing, rename("kopia.txt", DB) make sure the file kopia.txt is exists near the exe file while you run this application from outside your IDE.